# Move rows between 2 linked tabulator tables

Tags: tabulator

I have setup 2 connected tabulator tables which work fine. I can move rows with the drag and drop method but I am also trying to move rows between those 2 tables with a click on tick/cross like this :

Table 1 definition:

```
...
{formatter:"buttonTick", align:"center", cellClick:function(e, cell){cell.getRow().move();}},
...
```

Table 2 definition:

```
...
{formatter:"buttonCross", align:"center", cellClick:function(e, cell){cell.getRow().move();}},
...
```

This doesn't works because .move() isn't recognized as a valid function. I also tried cell.getRow().send() instead of cell.getRow().move() but also without any success. I cannot find the function in the documentation to trigger to row transfer from one table to the other table by a cell clik. Any help is welcome. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding the row data to the second table. assuming that the example below is in table 1 and you want to move the data to table 2 you would need a ***cellClick*** function similar to this:

```
cellClick:function(e, cell){
    //add data to second table
    table2.addRow(cell.getData());

    //delete current row
    cell.getRow().delete();
}
```

Im not sure where you got the ***move*** or ***send*** functions from, they do not exist. Have a read of the [Component Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/components) for a full list of all the functions available on the different types of component